# Optimizing sql statements to reduce MySQL server load

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

```
$sql1 = "SELECT questions FROM last_check_date WHERE user_id=? ORDER BY questions DESC LIMIT 1";
$sql2 = "SELECT id FROM questions WHERE add_dt>?";
```

What do statements above do?

When I execute `sql1`, it gets last check date for user.

Then I'm executing second query, to fetch all id's where add date>last check date (from `sql1`)  and return affected rows count.

What I want to do is to merge this 2 statements into 1, and optimize query count. Following problem may occur:

There is no row for user in `$sql1`: must select all rows in `sql2` and return affected rows count.

I can't figure out how it must look like.. Thx in advance

## UPDATE

`SHOW CREATE TABLE last_check_date;` result is

```
CREATE TABLE `last_check_date` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `questions` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `users` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And `SHOW CREATE TABLE questions;`

```
CREATE TABLE `questions` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `question` text NOT NULL,
  `var_a` text NOT NULL,
  `var_b` text NOT NULL,
  `var_c` text NOT NULL,
  `var_d` text NOT NULL,
  `var_e` text NOT NULL,
  `subject` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `chapter` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `section` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `paragraph` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `rank` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `add_dt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `answer` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_chapters-id` (`chapter`),
  KEY `fk_paragraphs-id` (`paragraph`),
  KEY `fk_subjects-id` (`subject`),
  KEY `fk_sections-id` (`section`),
  KEY `fk_author-id` (`author_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_author-id` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_chapters-id` FOREIGN KEY (`chapter`) REFERENCES `chapters` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_paragraphs-id` FOREIGN KEY (`paragraph`) REFERENCES `paragraphs` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_sections-id` FOREIGN KEY (`section`) REFERENCES `sections` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_subjects-id` FOREIGN KEY (`subject`) REFERENCES `subjects` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: that has to be with a JOIN, we need to know more about the structure of the tables to know which column are commons

Comment: please post `SHOW CREATE TABLE last_check_date;` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE questions;` results. On the other hand, it is pretty unclear what you are actually retrieving and/or the datatypes: what is supposed to be the "questions" column? Definetly not a date right?

Comment: @Sebas yed it's date. As you see from tables name, there are all dates inside

Comment: @Sebas Are u sure that  `SHOW CREATE TABLE last_check_date;` works? It doesn't give any result

Comment: yes, check here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "
    SELECT q.id 
    FROM questions q
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT questions 
        FROM last_check_date 
        WHERE user_id=? 
        ORDER BY questions 
        DESC LIMIT 1
    ) l ON q.add_dt > l.questions"

$rs = mysql_query($sql);
$rowcount = mysql_num_rows($rs);
```

I don't know yet the proper syntax for PDO/MYSQLI, please adapt to your prefered driver.

Comment: What if last_check_date table is empty? In my case it returns 0 even if there is 3 questions in questions table

Comment: the left join will include null values from the joined table. So if nothing is returned from the subquery all rows from `questions q` should be returned.

Answer (score 1):

See below. I have assumed that if there are no records in `last_check_date` that you still want to show questions (in that case all of them).

```
select q.id
from questions q
left outer join (
    select max(questions) as questions
    from last_check_date
    where user_id = ?
) lcd on q.add_date > lcd.questions
where user_id = ?
order by questions desc
```

Comment: Why limit 1 ?? If there are no records that means user hasn't checked any question yet. It must return all questions count.

Comment: @epic_syntax Oops, typo. Removed now.

Comment: The problem is, getting error message `table last_check_date doesn't exist`, but I 100% know that there is no typo, and table exists